# Is there a way to get values out of a map in a MATLAB mex file?

Tags: matlab, mex

I have a function that I'm writing as a MATLAB mex file. This function has to use MEX because it is interfacing with a piece of hardware in C++. There are a lot of options that can be set, and I would like to use a `containers.Map` to pass them. (Otherwise, I'd need a huge number of function parameters.)

I don't see any way of accessing the Map's operator that retrieves values using keys. I tried using `mexCallMATLAB`, but my various approaches failed. Is there a way to do this?

I thought maybe Map implemented this operator using `subsref`, but this fails in MATLAB, so I'm guessing the equivalent in a mex file would fail, too:

```
dict = containers.Map('foo', 3)
subsref(dict, struct('type', '.', 'subs', 'foo'))
```

Comment: Can you just use a struct? Then you could use `mxGetField` and other related functions.

Comment: Maybe - I'm looking into that now.

Comment: Yes - that works for me. Thanks! I guess I'll leave this question open, though, since someone might still want an answer about Maps.

Comment: Great. It would help if you edited your question to provide a minimal example of what you're trying to do (it's not clear to me why you need to use `subsindex`).

Comment: You could also just create individual setter methods for your properties and/or use a Builder design pattern. This is not common in Matlab, but this is generally how it's done in languages such as C++

Comment: Added my example. I was trying to reverse engineer how the key retrieval operator works so I could do it in mex-land, but I didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upvote for @nirvana-msu for getting me on the right track. Also, thanks to @horchler for suggesting that using a `struct` instead is a better idea. Here's how to access a `containers.Map` in C++ after making one in MATLAB with a field named `foo`:

```cpp
#include <mex.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
    mxArray *args[2];
    args[0] = const_cast<mxArray*>(prhs[0]);

    const char **fields = (const char **) mxCalloc(2, sizeof(*fields));
    fields[0] = "type";
    fields[1] = "subs";

    args[1] = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, 1, 2, fields);
    auto typeStr = mxCreateString("()");
    mxSetField(args[1], 0, "type", typeStr);
    auto mapKey = mxCreateString("foo");
    mxSetField(args[1], 0, "subs", mapKey);

    mxArray *output;
    mexCallMATLAB(1, &output, 2, args, "subsref");
    mexPrintf("%f\n", mxGetScalar(output));
    mxDestroyArray(args[1]);
    mxFree(fields);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using wrong `'type'` in `subsref` - use `'()'` instead, because you're accessing the values using `()` notation in `containers.Map`, and not using a dot notation like in structures). The following method works:

```
dict = containers.Map('foo', 3);
subsref(dict, struct('type', '()', 'subs', 'foo'))

ans =
     3
```

As a side note, I'm not really sure if using `containers.Map` is the best way. Your `C++` code would be much cleaner if you create explicit setter methods. If there are too many properties, [Builder design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) can be helpful.